Confusion about Static IP assigned by ISP
I subscribed to an ISP service to provide me with Internet service and a static IP. They emailed me a static IP. I set up a web server and pointed the A address of that domain to the static IP provided and all is fine.
The confusion I have is that when I use one of the what-is-your-ip address sites, I get an IP address which is different than the static IP address assigned to me. What is more confusing is that the website running on the assigned static IP but connected to the same connection also works. In other words, has the ISP allocated multiple IP addresses to the same connection and even if that is the case, it is kind of confusing on how that will work.  Any basic explanation will help.
EDIT: The router is a Nokia Model G-2425G-A, a GPON router. Has one incoming fibre optic line and four LAN ports, labeled LAN1... LAN4. The WAN IP address reported by the router is the static IP address assigned to me. It is a public IP address of course. The what-is-your-ip address is different. For some reason, I expected the what-is-your-ip to be the same as the Static IP. On the router, I port-forwarded port 80 and 443 to the web server. It appears that for incoming connections, static ip is used. For local browsing some dynamically assigned ip is used. Is this normal?

There are several ways to set this up, though the basic principle is that an Internet connection has never been limited to a single IP address to begin with. What WAN technology is being used? (Cable, ADSL, LTE? PPPoE or not?) What 'WAN' IP address is reported by your router? Is it a public address or a private one? Does it match either the "what-is-your-ip" address or the static address?

@grawity_u1686  You got me a partial answer already. The WAN IP address reported by the router is the static IP address assigned to me. It is a public IP address of course.  The what-is-your-ip address is different. For some reason, I expected the what-is-your-ip to be the same as the Static IP.  On the router, I port-forwarded port 80 and 443 to the web server. It appears that for incoming connections, static ip is used. For local browsing some dynamically assigned ip is used. Is this normal?

Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question.


for incoming connections, static ip is used

For incoming connections, the address that the client wants to connect to is used.

It appears that for incoming connections, static ip is used. For local browsing some dynamically assigned ip is used. Is this normal?

Generally not (it's useless to do so), but it may be an artifact of how your ISP's network is managed, or even incomplete configuration on their part.
For example, if your ISP's default is for residential customers to be placed behind CGNAT, they might have forgotten to switch your connection to bypass the ISP's NAT gateway, so even though you already have a dedicated public IP address, your packets continue to (uselessly) be NATed.
They might also be doing this deliberately, for the same reason that (as I've heard from Germany, for example) some ISPs insist on reconnecting you with a different dynamic address every midnight – i.e. to meet some or other privacy regulation.
(Though it is also possible for your own router to have multiple IP addresses assigned and be locally NATing packets to the wrong one – even if that's unlikely – so I'd still want to verify that this is not your own router doing this; depending on the router's capabilities (and depending on what WAN technology is being used), I'd run a packet capture (tcpdump) on its WAN interface to make sure the outgoing HTTP packets come from the static IP address and not from some other address.)

I am accepting this answer because it substantially clarified my doubts. I did Edit my question with more data. I understand that incoming connection is for the ip address in the destination address of the IP packet, which in this case will be the DNS A record. I do get http response sent back for my test page but I do not know the source address in the response sent. I will try to install some browser extensions to see this. How do I run a packet capture (tcpdump) on its WAN interface? I mean I cannot install wireshark or tcpdump on it.

The source address of the response is the same as the destination address of your request – if it were anything else, you wouldn't even establish the TCP connection, much less send the HTTP request. (Standard TCP doesn't support connection migration, which is in part why things like QUIC and MPTCP are being developed.) But NAT is usually stateful – if the initial inbound request didn't go through DNAT, then the reply won't go through SNAT either – so all of that doesn't reveal anything. What's more interesting is whether outbound requests from your LAN (e.g. to websites) use the new address…

If the router were separate from the GPON ONT, it would be easier, but with a combined unit there's probably no way to check. But really it's unlikely to be the router's fault, as I assume it's using DHCP or PPPoE (not static IP) and those can autoconfigure only address anyway... the paragraph was more about the technical possibility of a router having both IPs simultaneously.
